# How to specify the generated jar path in m2e

Tags: m2eclipse, m2e

I use m2e. I have dynamic web project A, java project B and project A is dependent on project B. I want the JAR file that is generated in the target folder of project B to be moved to the WebContent/lib of project A. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Enter Project B as dependency in the POM of project A. That ist the prerequiste for maven to resolve the dependency from A to B.

2) In the Eclipse project preferences of project A make sure the in the section "maven" the option "Resolve dependencies form Workspace projects" option is enables (should be by default.

Usually, this should do it